# How to get value from an exe in VB

Tags: vb.net, gdal

I have to get value returned from `gdalinfo.exe` which needs arguments ,
I have to give an image name, latitude and longitude along with `exe`.

I formed a string like this:

```
str1 = "gdallocationinfo"+""+"-geoloc "+""+"-valonly"+""+"d:\test.tif"+lon.ToString+lon.ToString"
```

after running this, one value will be returned from `exe.`
I've tried `procid=shell()`
and it is executing the command but not able to store the value.

I've also tried with `TestProcess.startinfo.RedirectStandardoutput`
but no use.

Comment: your code won't work since the string concat operator in VB.NET is not `+`! It's the `&` sign

Comment: @Radinator: `+` also concatenates strings in VB.NET. Still, his example is missing a few spaces in the string.

Comment: If you want to redirect the standard output stream of a process then you have to start that process by calling `Process.Start`.  Create a `ProcessStartInfo` object first, set its properties, then pass it to `Process.Start`.  Note that the redirection must be configured BEFORE starting the process and the name of the file to execute and the commandline arguments are provided separately.

Comment: Also, that string concatenation is not only ugly but also silly.  What's the point of concatenating empty string literals?  All that does it make it harder to read and, therefore, more error prone.  Learn to use the `String.Format` method or, in VB 2015, string interpolation.